# Recommended apps for securing/protecting a new desktop machine install?

Tags: installation, security, desktop-computer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What are some “must have” Windows programs?](https://superuser.com/questions/1241/what-are-some-must-have-windows-programs)
>   [What are some “must have” Mac OS X programs?](https://superuser.com/questions/1191/what-are-some-must-have-mac-os-x-programs)
>   [Free antivirus solutions for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows)

I'm hoping to harness the collective tips of superuser to gather recommended apps/configurations to keep a new desktop clean, virus free, and hopefully lower software rot.

I ask because I've recently come across tools like dropbox, deepfreeze, returnil, etc, and I'm curious what other ones are out there to protect a new box.

I personally am interested in Windows, but feel free to comment on whatever OS you'd like, freeware or otherwise.  Ideally specify the OS in your answer(s).

One answer per program please.  Then, rather than duplicate posts, vote for the program if it is already listed.

**UPDATE:**

It's been noted that there are other questions similar to this one [1], so I'd ask that these answers focus on **security** and **protection**.

[1] Related questions:

- https://superuser.com/questions/1241/what-are-some-must-have-windows-programs
- https://superuser.com/questions/1191/what-are-some-must-have-mac-os-x-programs
- https://superuser.com/questions/1430/must-have-linux-software
- https://superuser.com/questions/3855/must-have-networking-security-tools

Comment: this appears to be a duplicate of the following questions: http://superuser.com/questions/1241/what-are-some-must-have-windows-programs .. http://superuser.com/questions/1191/what-are-some-must-have-mac-os-x-programs .. http://superuser.com/questions/1430/must-have-linux-software ... i'm not convinced the caveat *"for a new install"* is enough of a differentiation.

Comment: Good catch.  You very well may be right.  I was hoping for more of a slant on 'must have towards securing your box', but maybe those other ones cover it better?

Comment: there's also http://superuser.com/questions/3855/must-have-networking-security-tools -- a bit more technician/testing related.  if this is going to stay alive, i think it should focus on the desktop-software-for-protecting aspect.

Comment: Sure.  I'll try editing the question to angle it as such.  If it still seems to duplicate other questions, feel free to nominate to close it.

Answer (score 2):

**MalwareBytes AntiMalware** - Best antiMalware/Spyware program available atm imo free version

Answer (score 0):

Windows/Mac/Linux/Mobile: Mozilla Firefox - free

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Security Essentials - fast, free, light, and awesome.

Answer (score 0):

WinPatrol 2010 - Free Edition - highly recommend, helps prevent computer rot by controling services, startup programs, etc...

Answer (score 0):

**Avira Antivir** - Free version low resources use and i have had better results then with Norton, Kaspersky, McAfee etc.

Answer (score 0):

**CCleaner** - Cleans temp, cookies, cache, empties recycle bin, and deletes unused registry entries, plus it has an uninstaller which is much better than the default windows

Answer (score 0):

**Google Chrome**. So many exploits are pointed towards Internet Explorer that it's worth it just to get away from it. Also, there are tons of awesome extensions like AdBlock that just flat out make the switch worth it.

Comment: I'd argue that IE8 is safer than Firefox and Safari when running a Windows 7 machine...

Comment: yeah. but there was no OS specified and i still think adblock plus is worth switching for any day of the week.

Comment: one app per answer.  firefox was [posted earlier](http://superuser.com/questions/128621/recommended-apps-for-new-desktop-machine-install/128623#128623), so i'm editing that out.